# Find out if selected cell is in databodyrange

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro set up to perform a chunk of code in an 'onclick' event, and I'm trying to determine if they've selected a numeric value in a table range. An example of my table is below, and I'm trying to figure out if they've selected a number > 0 in the second column. I know how to reference the second column of a specific table, something like:

```
ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange
```

but I'm not sure how to figure out if the selected cell is in that range. Any suggestions? Thanks so much for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Intersect`.

```
Dim rangeToCheck as Range
Set rangeToCheck = Intersect(ActiveCell, ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange)

If Not rangeToCheck Is Nothing Then
    If IsNumeric(ActiveCell.Value) Then 
        If ActiveCell.Value > 0 Then
            ' do the suff
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table has filters then you have to check the visible cells only

Try this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ListObjects(1).ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    Dim hit As Boolean
    hit = Not Application.Intersect(r, Target) Is Nothing

    If hit Then
        Range("A1").Value = "Inside"
    Else
        Range("A1").Value = "Outside"
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

otherwise for all visible and non-visible cells use

```
Set r = ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange
```

Comment: Don't you need to specify `ListColumns(2)` as well?

Comment: Fantastic, thank you @BigBen and ja72 for your suggestions! I had no idea intersect existed.